# Firefox won't prompt me to save login

Tags: firefox, login, auto-login

I'm using a webpage at work that requires that I login frequently.  When I first started using the website I chose 'no thanks' to firefox prompt to save the login.  I want it to save my login, but the website's url isn't in the list of 'exceptions', so how do I get it to prompt me to save this login again?

Answer (score 3):

Removing your cookies and clearing the page cache should do the trick but before trying that as you may prefer to keep them, you could check:

Tools->Options->Security->Passwords->Exceptions

Another alternative is to create a bookmark and in the location put the following Javascript, to tell Firefox to save the password:
[Password Saver](http://cybernetnews.com/tweak-firefoxs-password-saver-without-an-extension/)